# echo login error in different page, specific div

Tags: php, html, css

Delayed too long with this issue. I have a index.php including form and login.php handeling it.

How do I post the errors in a specific div in index.php?
Here is the Index.php container, no php code in idnex.php yet.

```
    <div id="container">
    <section>
        <h1>ברוכים הבאים לאתר קופונים</h1>
        <h2>המקום בו תוכלו למצוא קופונים בסביבתכם</h2>
        <hr>
    </section>

    <section id="mainpage">
            <p class="welcome">
                אנא התחבר בכדי ליצור ולראות קופונים בקרבתך</br>
                <a href="php/register.php">הירשם לאתר</a> 
            </p>

            <form action="php/login.php" method="post" class="form">
                <p class="email">
                    <input type="text" name="email" /> :דואר אלקטרוני</br>
                </p>
                <p class="password">
                    <input type="password" name="password" /> :סיסמא</br>
                </p>
                <p class="submit">  
                    <input type="submit" value="היכנס" />  
                </p>  
            </form>
    </section>
</div>
```

and here is the login.php error reporting section

```
            //check matching input
        if($email == $dbemail && $password = $dbpassword){
            $_SESSION['email'] = $dbemail;
            include('../index.php');
            header('members.php');

        }
        else{
            include('../index.php');
            echo "Incorrect Password<style text-align:center;/>";
        }
    }

} else
    include('../index.php');
    die('<p class="error">User does not exist</p>');
} else
    include('../index.php');
    die('Please enter a Email and password');
```

tried this

```
include('../index.php');
    die('<p class="error">User does not exist</p>');
```

can't manage to specifically position it under the Submit button (using margin: 0 auto so left and right changes)

Thanks for any help given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your `login.php` file:

```
} else {
   // error happened
   $error = '<p class="error">User does not exist</p>'
   include('../index.php');
   exit;
...
```

and your index.php file:

```
<form action="php/login.php" method="post" class="form">
<?php
if(isset($error)) echo $error;
?>
<p class="email">
   <input type="text" name="email" /> :דואר אלקטרוני</br>
...
```

Comment: Not working for me my friends, all it says is undefined on $error in index.php

Comment: Got error In session.  "A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() "  What To Do Sir @Peter

Comment: @ankitsuthar you have session_start twice somewhere in your code

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, is that your `login.php` file directly `echo`'s the error message out. A better method would be to save the message into a variable - even a session variable would suffice (as it looks like you're not using OOP, by the example code).

Try updating the error messages to not use `echo`, but instead maybe:

```
$_SESSION['error_message'] = "Incorrect Password<style text-align:center;/>";
```

And then, in `index.php`, exactly where you want it to be displayed add:

```
     <p class="submit">  
          <input type="submit" value="היכנס" />  
     </p>  
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['error_message'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['error_message'];
    unset($_SESSION['error_message']); // clear the message to prevent duplicate displays
}
?>
```

As it looks like you want to include the `index.php` file when the actual error occurs, you can set a local variable right before the call to `include('../index.php');` inside `login.php`, like this:

```
} else {
    $errMsg = "Incorrect Password<style text-align:center;/>";
    include('../index.php');
}
```

And like the above example modified `index.php`, you can do the same here like:

```
    </p>
</form>
<?php if ($errMsg) { echo $errMsg; } ?>
```

Comment: [why did you copied my answer (second part)? :D](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12112991/revisions)

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski Didn't copy; my original had used OOP to store/display the error message - after re-reading the question (and siding with my original "doesn't look like OOP statement") I changed it to something more close to the OP's question.. but I agree - they are the same =P